# Select & count in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a query I want to display total number of count in Each record in single row. I am using cassandra lucene Index .

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE expr(my_index, \'{
                               filter: {
                                 type: "boolean",
                                 must: [
                                    {type: "wildcard", field: "location", value: "*%s*"},
                                 ]
                               }
                            }\') limit 10; '
```

The above gives me 10 result, but I want to get the total count in every row.

Comment: If I try sql1="select count(*) from the table it gives me complete Total records.

Comment: My problem is I am using WildCard which has to give all the matches found in single record...

Comment: Sample data and sample required output will help... what do you mean by total count in each record

Comment: you may index required column on which you want to get a count. Once it is indexed you can use wildcards.